# Can server 2008 session broker be used in a 2008 R2 terminal server farm

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

i'm building a terminal server farm using two 2008 R2 terminal (remote desktop) servers but i do not have a third R2 server in my network for the session broker so i was wondering if i can use a 2008 server for the session broker.  i would imagine that this would work but i wanted to ask if anyone knows for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a link to a document that mentions this, but my experience when I added our first 2008R2 server tells me that the answer to this is yes a 2008R2 terminal servers will work with a 2008 session broker.  I am not certain if it is 100% functional though.